# ScrollView is cut inside main layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview inside my main linear layout like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                       ---content---

              </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollVIew>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When I scroll the textview  'Full Name' is cut and not displayed properly.

[image]

I have searched all solutions and also tried following both:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

But it didn't worked. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Now I found the answer from android developers official page on Google Plus:

I need to set     `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` along with     `android:clipToPadding="false"`.

This is exactly what matched with my issue: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LpAA7q4jw9M